# SPRING MVC - Error with autowired beans

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

I have this maven project with its modules

Parent

|_____Model

|_____Persistence

|_____Service

```
         |_ service-context.xml
```

|_____View

```
         |_ spring/app-config.xml
```

**I have this controller
controllers.HomeController   in the View module**

```
@Controller

public class HomeController {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

private IServicioService servicioService;

@RequestMapping(value="/home.htm")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.info("Returning hello view");

    return new ModelAndView("home.jsp");
}

@Autowired
public void setServicioService(IServicioService servicioService) {
    this.servicioService = servicioService;
}
```

**And my service   servicios.ServicioService in the services module**

```
@Service
public class ServicioService implements IServicioService{

private ServicioDao servicioDao;

public ServicioService(){}

/*************************** Gett&Sett ****************************/

public ServicioDao getServicioDao() {
    return servicioDao;
}

public void setServicioDao(ServicioDao servicioDao) {
    this.servicioDao = servicioDao;
}
```

}

**The IServicioService hasnt a @Service
The ServicioService  bean is defined in service-context.xml like this**

```
<bean id="servicioService" class="servicios.ServicioService">
    <property name="servicioDao"   ref="servicioDao" />
</bean>
```

**And my app-config.xml  is importing the service-context.xml **

```
   <import resource="classpath*:service-context.xml" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
```

Idk why is giving me this

No matching bean of type [servicios.ServicioService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably lies inside of xml configuration.
Try adding in your app-config.xml line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="servicios" />
```

After that you should do the same with your daos

Comment: Thank you so much!! Was it, i added that line and it worked